# Setting up a simple signup/signin with Doorkeeper and JSONAPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper, jsonapi-resources

**Short story**

I'm having a difficult time to add Doorkeeper to my working JSONAPI project.

Since I'm new to it, I think one of the biggest problems is the understanding of the framework.

Basically I need any further requests to contain an AccessToken so I can authorize them to use my app. The first two things, of course, will be the registration and login.

After some reading I found out Doorkeeper assumes (is it correct?) a Resource Server and a Authorization Server. But I am both of them. And this is driving me crazy.

I don't exactly know what I have to do and what is optional since every implementation seems to have its own features and differences.

**Problem starts here**

So following this guide https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Interacting-as-an-OAuth-client-with-Doorkeeper

I first created an app (I believe I have to create an app to my own) and provided a `Redirect URI` that isn't yet created (I added http://localhost:3000/panel, but there is nothing responding to it). And I left `scopes` blank.

Then the guide mentions a `client_id`... I'm assuming it is the * application id* the Application generator provided.

And it also mentions an authorization code that I still don't own. Apparently I need to 'authorize' the app. There is a button 'authorize' but when I click it it throws an error

> fail "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{**FILE**}"

And the configuration file `initializers/doorkeeper.rb` is all commented. But the official guide (https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#configuration) doesn't mention any configuration.

What is the basic configuration for Doorkeeper? Any other insights about my project that would help me?

**@edit**

Alright, I managed to give one step ahead. 
Removing that line that thew the error and uncommenting the last line of that same block

```
User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
```

The error changes. Now it says it doesn't recognize this variable `new_user_session_url`. Changing to the one suggested in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN9BylV81rw

`routes.login_url` and only `login_url` (says `routes` is not defined) didn't work too. Still the same error.

I think I'm back to my first questions. I'm not sure that is optional and what is not, and what the gem created by default and what i have to do myself.

What do I need to do at this point?